# lightning global search url

Tags: lightning, search, global-search

Is there a readable URL for global search in Lightning, similar to Classic that use &startURL=/_ui/search/ui/UnifiedSearchResults?str=valueToSearch ?.

I want to use this URL to add to Chrome omnibar so that the reps can easily search a record in salesforce. But the lightning URL is encoded and I am not able to figure out what should url should I add to the search engine.

Answer (score 1):

This code works in lightning

```
var searchQuery = 'test@test.com';
var stringToEncode = '{"componentDef":"forceSearch:search","attributes":{"term":"'+searchQuery + '","scopeMap":{"type":"TOP_RESULTS"},"context": {"disableSpellCorrection":false,"SEARCH_ACTIVITY":{"term":"'+ searchQuery + '"}}}}';
var encodedString = btoa(stringToEncode);

var globalSearchUrl ="/one/one.app?source=alohaHeader#" +encodedString
```

pass this url to window.open or use it in workspaceAPI.openTab

Comment: This still works for me.  It's reliable only when opening the URL in a new tab.  Otherwise, for example if I paste the query into the address bar of a tab that is already opened to a page on my salesforce instance, I get an error : `Your search term must have 2 or more characters.` Using a url constructed this way  in anchors with `target="_blank"`, works.